# Left join to achieve minus is not working

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table1 and table2 as like follows:

table1:
[image]

Table2:
[image]

When i perform the following query between the tables:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      empid
     ,ename
     ,sal
     ,deptno
    FROM
      table1
    GROUP BY
      1,2,3,4
  ) AS a
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      empid
     ,ename
     ,sal
     ,deptno
    FROM
      table2
  ) AS b
    ON
    a.empid = b.empid
      AND a.ename = b.ename
      AND a.sal = b.sal
      AND a.deptno = b.deptno
WHERE
  b.empid IS NULL
  AND b.ename IS NULL
  AND b.sal IS NULL
  AND b.deptno IS NULL;
```

I am getting output like as follows:
[image]

We dont have `Minus` in Bigquery. That is the reason to perform `Left Join`.

The output I require is Table1 minus table2.

Please help me on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table1`
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table2`
```

Comment: Is there any function or operator in legacy SQL to do the same,  why I am getting all nulls from table2 even though there are matching records.

Comment: are you bound to legacy sql? you have not mentioned this o(. anyway - No - only UNION ALL functionality is available for legacy sql and it is implemented by using the comma, which is the UNION ALL operator in BigQuery Legacy SQL. see more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#from)

Comment: BigQuery Team strongly recommends migrating to BigQuery Standard SQL. See more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: Thankyou Mikhail for your response

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how your query produces that output, as you only have 4 columns in derived table A, but you claim your output produces 8

It can be simplified, I think:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table 2 b on a.empid = b.empid WHERE b.empid is null
```

Surely, the point of a primary key is to uniquely identify a row, so we only need to join on it, we don't usually factor the other data into whether we should or shouldn't return the row if the question is "which employees in *this* list are not in *that* list?"

If b.empid is a PK, then the only way it can be null is if the join didn't work out, so its the only column we need to test for being null

You asked

> "why are all my b columns null?"

This is because rather than just joining on the primary key, you've joined on ALL columns:

```
  ON
  a.empid = b.empid
  AND a.ename = b.ename
  AND a.sal = b.sal
  AND a.deptno = b.deptno
```

It is a hard rule in the world of databases that "nothing is ever equal to null, not even another null"

```
1 = NULL --false
'a' = NULL --false
'NULL' = NULL --false
NULL = NULL --false
```

You can never get TRUE out of a comparison using = (or any other operator like <, >, LIKE) if one side is null. The ONLY thing that produces TRUE when working with nulls is the `IS NULL` operator (and also IS NOT NULL)

```
1 IS NULL --false
NULL IS NULL --true
```

Going back to your query, remember that "if something on one side of an = is null, the result is FALSE"

Here are your rows:

[image]

Here are the reasons why the B table rows are null:

```
EMPID   Reason
null    a.empid is null, a.empid = b.empid is FALSE because nothing is 
        ever equal to a null, no row from B is matching
101     a.sal is null, a.sal = b.sal is FALSE because nothing is ever 
        equal to a null, no row from B is matching, B is all null
104     a.deptno is null, a.deptno = b.deptno is FALSE because nothing is
        ever equal to a null, no row from B is matching, B is all null
105     a.sal is null, see reason for 101
102     there is no row for empid 102 in table b, b is all null
103     there is no row for empid 103 in table b, b is all null
```

So there you go - all B rows are nulls either because there is no matching row, or because you asked the database to join on a.somecolumn = b.somecolumn and at least one of the sides was =, and using `NULL = anything` is always false, false -> no row matched -> all B columns are null

#### What should you do to "fix" it?

Either join on JUST the primary key like I said above (and remember one of your primary keys is null so it will never appear) or convert the nulls to something that can be compared with = like this:

```
  ON
  COALESCE(a.empid, -1) = COALESCE(b.empid, -1)
  AND COALESCE(a.ename, 'mr_noname') = COALESCE(b.ename, 'mr_noname')
  AND COALESCE(a.sal, -1) = COALESCE(b.sal, -1)
  AND COALESCE(a.deptno, -1) = COALESCE(b.deptno, -1)
```

COALESCE works from left to right returning the first argument that isn't null. COALESCE(a.sal, -1) will hence return -1 if a.sal is null

Comment: There is no primary key columns in both the tables

Comment: Why I am getting all nulls from table2 even though there are matching records.

Comment: As I pointed out at the start, there is absolutely no way a database will return those results for the query you have posted, because `SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT 1,2,3,4 FROM t) a` can only ever return 4 columns - A has 4 columns, and SELECT a.* cannot hence produce 8 columns.

Comment: On your question of *Why I am getting all nulls from table2* - i'll make an edit to my answer. Check in 5 minutes